# Merging multiple GeoTIFF's with gdal_merge creates a solid gray GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-merge

I have these two GeoTIFF's:

https://terrafrost.com/gdal/1.tif

https://terrafrost.com/gdal/2.tif

I'm trying to merge them by doing `gdal_merge -o result.tif 1-dark.tif 2-dark.tif` but when I do the result is just a solid gray image:

https://terrafrost.com/gdal/result.tif

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Do I need to do some pre-processing on the input GeoTIFF's? Maybe another tool would be better?

Comment: Originaly you have two single band GeoTiffs with 256 color palette, but only two colors are used (white and green). The result of gdal_merge is a single band gray image. Your result is OK, but the background color is black and the foreground color is white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gdalbuildvrt it better than gdal_merge.py for most use cases. However, your issue is easy to fix. Gdalinfo shows that source images are paletted, and both are having the same color table

```
 0: 253,253,253,0
 1: 17,204,142,255
 2: 0,0,0,255
 3: 0,0,0,255
 4: 0,0,0,255
...
```

From the documentation https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html:

> **-pct**
>
> Grab a pseudo-color table from the first input image, and use it for
> the output. Merging pseudo-colored images this way assumes that all
> input files use the same color table.

So the gdal_merge command to use is

```
gdal_merge -pct -o result.tif 1.tif 2.tif
```

How to do the same with gdalbuildvrt:

```
gdalbuildvrt test.vrt 1.tif 2.tif
gdal_translate test.vrt result.tif
```

Your original result.tif image is not solid gday. Running `gdalinfo result.tif -stats` shows that is has values 0 and 1 like the original paletted images have. But because the color table was not copied the image turned into grayscale with totally black and almost black pixels that eye cannot separate.

```
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
STATISTICS_MEAN=0.012810842015339
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.11245765577406
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following gdal_merge command line to merge your images.
This will produce a 26KB output TIF instead of 9MB paletted:

```
gdal_merge -o result.tif -co NBITS=1 -co COMPRESS=CCITTFAX4 -co PHOTOMETRIC=MINISWHITE -co NBITS=1  1.tif 2.tif
```

Comment: Great alternative if the color of the lines does not matter.